# overriding ansible_become_pass w/ command line option --ask-become-pass

Tags: ansible

I am having issues with the interaction between "ansible_become_pass" and "--ask-become-pass".

In group_vars/all I have set the default become-pass since on each machine there is an ansible user with this pass:

```
ansible_become_pass: "{{ default_ansible_user_pass }}"
```

However, in exactly one playbook I need to have the become-pass be set via the "--ask-become-pass" commandline option (this playbook is the one that creates this ansible user for the first time). However, the playbook fails with :

```
fatal: [some_host_name]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Incorrect sudo password"}
```

because it is using the value from group_vars/all instead of the value I passed via commandline. Temporarily commenting out the value in group_vars/all fixes the problem.

Is this the correct behaviour ? Any ideas what I am doing wrong? I would assume that command-line options take precedence over group_vars.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting this issue :
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/42875

```
-K has a lower precedence than inventory provided ansible_become_pass so ansible_become_pass is the value used. During CLI argument parsing, we don't know what the inventory configuration is yet, so you may be prompting for unnecessary data.
```

It seems extremely unintuitive since I believe the general convention is that command-line-arguments take precendence over variables.

As a work-around I simply passed the password via :

```
ansible-playbook ... -e ansible_become_pass=passwordIDontWantSeenInBashHistory
```